# JavaFX Linechart zoom scroll

Tags: javafx, linechart

I want to implement a linechart in JavaFX which should be zoomable / scrollable.

I used SceneBuilder for creating the Chart and all the data is shown up correctly.
My goal is that the user is able to zoom in and to scroll to the sides (x - axis).

I found many topics about zooming and i already tried to implement it, but it just changes the scale and is not a solution for my problem.

I tried to draw a mockup for my chart.
Maybe someone can help me with that problem.
( https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13774526/mockup.jpg )

kind regards
Christian

Comment: Ref https://community.oracle.com/thread/2534849?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

you can use JFXutils, there is a zoom function in this library, very useful and easy to implement in your project. [jfxutils link](https://github.com/gillius/jfxutils)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this approach for scaling/scrolling the Line chart.

1. Horizontal and Vertical Sliders shall be placed near X & Y axis of the line chart.
2. The min and max values of the all the series altogether is calculated and set for the sliders respectively (for both axes).
3. On drag of this slider (its listener), the corresponding scaled value is added with the respective AXIS's Start value.
4. The tick lengths & counts must be updated during each scale event.

Answer (score 0):

Because native charts don't provide zooming, panning etc, I have implemented a library using the plotly.js charts.
You can have a look on github it's open-source. Maybe this can be helpful in your case.

https://github.com/jasrodis/javafx-dataviewer/